# Maelstorm jquery xmlrpc getting blank error

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-rpc

I was looking for a jquery library for XML-RPC and found this one: https://github.com/maelstrom/jquery-xmlrpc

I followed the instructions which were very strait forward but ended up getting an empty error response.

I'm sure that my xml-rpc resource works fine because I already access it from an ios app - so the problem is with how I am using this library I think.

I have a simple method that multiplies two numbers that are passed in to test the XMP-RPC.

```
            $.xmlrpc({

                url: 'http://www.URL.com/xmlrpc.php',

                methodName: 'demo.multiplyTwoNumbers',

                params: [5, 4],

                success: function(response, status, jqXHR) { 

                alert("response: <" + response + "> jqXHR: <" + jqXHR + "> status: <" + status + ">");

                },

                error: function(jqXHR, status, error) { 

                alert("error: <" + error + "> jqXHR: <" + jqXHR + "> status: <" + status + ">");

                }

            });
```

The alert I receive is this:

```
error: <> jqXHR: <[object Object]> status: <error>
```

I tried this with a few other methods in my xml-rpc server but no success. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely you are having the same problem as me. Namely that this library defaults to making XMLRPC requests with an HTTP OPTIONS request, rather than with a POST.

It's not clear to me if this can be changed, as I have gone through the documentation and see no references to a method to set this. That being said, this is built on top of jquery.ajax, which does support setting a request type. So probably there is a way.

Comment: Determined issue to be a SOP (same origin policy) violation. Based on your example code you are almost 100% suffering from the same problem. You may only make calls to domains upon which your javascript is served, you cannot make arbitrary calls like you would from an IOS application. Read more about SOP and why it's in place for more information

Comment: I'm on the same domain. I tried changing the url to a local path (which in my case is "..xmlrpc.php") but no luck

Comment: Oh! sorry, changed the url on the wrong request! Works perfectly now! Thank you so much!